# knitr - bottom figures on every page are cropped

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc

I am trying to produce a pdf using `knitr`, and the bottom figure of every page are cropped.

I used the following options:

```
output:
    pdf_document:
    fig_caption: no
    fig_crop: false
    latex_engine: xelatex 
    keep_tex: true
```

The last line keeps a separate copy of the figures, and they are complete!
I tried opening the document on several different computers (thinking it might be the pdf device driver), and the pdf document always comes out cropped.

I have the most recent version of Rstudio.

Any ideas?